# iOS pod related build error on simulator when using external IDE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, intellij-idea

I am currently working on a project in Flutter and am trying to include an SDK that does not have a Flutter wrapper. To do this, I created a plugin with method channels that will communicate with the native side of things.

Everything works fine and as it is supposed to on Android, and the application works perfectly on iOS when building from xCode. The build **fails** when I am using an external IDE, such as intellij or android studio. However, building it externally to a device from the 3rd party IDE works, so the problem seems to be directly related to a combination of the external IDE and the simulator.

The error I am receiving from the 3rd party IDE is:

```
/ios/Classes/SwiftRelevantSDKPlugin.swift:3:8: error: no such module 'RelevantSDK'
import RelevantSDK
```

And what seems to be the relevant warning is:

```
warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in 'RelevantSDK.xcframework RelevantSDK framework ios-arm64 ios-x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64).
```

I have added the pod requirement into the iOS podspec, and do not include the pod in my podfile.